# Create Pivot view in SQL from a SQL table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have the following table `TEMP`

[image]

I want to create a pivot view using SQL, Ordered by `CATEGORY` ASC ,by `LEVEL` DESC and `SET` ASC and fill in the `value` .

Expected output:

[image]

I have tried the following code but unable to get a workaround the aggregate part which is throwing an error:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         SET, LEVEL, CATEGORY, VALUE 
     FROM 
         TEMP 
     ORDER BY 
         CATEGORY ASC, LEVEL DESC, SET ASC) x
PIVOT 
    (value(VALUE) FOR RISK_LEVEL IN ('X','Y','Z') AND CATEGORY IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL')) p
```

Furthermore I want to know if there can be any method for dynamically adding the columns and arriving at this view for any table having the same columns (so that hardcoding can be avoided).

I know we can do this in Excel and transpose it, but I want the data to be stored in the db in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stored function(*or procedure*) might be created in order to create a SQL for Dynamic Pivoting, and the result set is loaded into a variable of type `SYS_REFCURSOR` :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Categories_RS RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols_1    VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols_2    VARCHAR2(32767);  
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( ''''||"level"||''' AS "'||"level"||'"' , ',' )
          WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY "level" DESC )
    INTO v_cols_1
    FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT "level"
            FROM temp
          );

  SELECT LISTAGG( 'MAX(CASE WHEN category = '''||category||''' THEN "'||"level"||'" END) AS "'||"level"||'_'||category||'"' , ',' )
          WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY category, "level" DESC )
    INTO v_cols_2
    FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT "level", category
            FROM temp
          );

  v_sql :=
  'SELECT "set", '|| v_cols_2 ||'
     FROM
     (
      SELECT *
        FROM temp
       PIVOT
       (
        MAX(value) FOR "level" IN ( '|| v_cols_1 ||' )
       )
      )
      GROUP BY "set"
      ORDER BY "set"'; 

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
```

in which I used two levels of pivoting : the first is within the inner query involving `PIVOT` Clause, and the second is in the outer query having the conditional aggregation logic. Notice that the order of levels should be in the descending order( `Z`, `Y`, `X` ) within the expected result as conforming to the description.

And then invoke

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_Categories_RS;
PRINT rc
```

from SQL Developer's Command Line in order to get the result set

*Btw, avoid using reserved keywords such as `set` and `level` as in your case. I needed to quote them in order to be able to use.*

Comment: Can we create this as a `procedure` rather than a function..? Further I have 30 different tables with different names and same columns . I think by this method I would need to create that many number of functions?

Comment: Also could you tell me or show me what  `t3` table is ? Shouldn't we pass the table as parameter to the `function` or `procedure`.

Comment: Hi @Scope , as I mentioned within the answer creating procedure is also possible if you need more than one parameter returning. For example `v_recordset` might be moved to procedure's parameter list such as `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Get_Categories_RS( .... , v_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, ... ) IS` as type stays the same. Nevertheless, you don't have to create a function(or procedure), may just find out you job within a code block together with a simple loop which takes values from  a DB table or array.The rest is up to you .Btw, I forgot to use your original table name `temp` (`t3`)..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to run it on commander ( outside the function or procedure), I got a "Result of String Concatenation Too Long " Error in the second `LISTAGG` query.Any workaround for this? How did you happen to execute it

Comment: Other sources have suggested `SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,colname,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY colname).GetClobVal(),',') AS LIST` for a workaround but I dont know if it works with Oracle 11g as it gives an error. Im unable to run the code because of this

Comment: You're welcome @Scope . I saw your new question. What you wrote is related to this Yes, there's a limitation for LISTAGG, I don't know any workaround. Since never worked with a lot of columns. Have you tried this answer with your current data which fits into LISTAGG ..? Is this helpful ?

Comment: No it didnt work. I'm getting one error trying to insert into `v_cols_2` . Is oracle 11 g so outdated that no one else is using it?Mine would have 12 columns max not more than that..

Comment: @Scope Have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=70bf221ab6eae07d26e8fec7d335b320) ...

Comment: I did see that, but I think its working as only 6 columns are inserted. Im still unable to run it. Righnow Im trying outside proc/function as the `exec` you provided is again showing as invalid. which is why im using `@ECHO ${v_cols_2 ||32767||varchar2}$
@ECHO ${v_cols_1 ||32767||varchar2}$` to declare then run it but yet failed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222456/discussion-between-scope-and-barbaros-ozhan).