# Convert ` LISTAGG` TO `XMLAGG`

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, listagg

How to convert `LISTAGG` with case statements to `XMLAGG` equivalent, so as to avoid the concatenation error.

```
@ECHO ${cols_2 ||32767||varchar2}$ --Declare variable

SELECT LISTAGG( 'MAX(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = '''||CATEGORY||''' THEN "'||"LEVEL"||'" END) AS "'||"LEVEL"||'_'||CATEGORY||'"' , ',' )
          WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY CATEGORY, "LEVEL" DESC )
    INTO cols_2
    FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT "LEVEL", CATEGORY
            FROM temp
          );
```

I tried this and I'm  getting an error saying `missing keyword`

```
@ECHO ${cols_2 ||32767||varchar2}$ --Declare variable

select rtrim (
          xmlagg (xmlelement (e, 'MAX(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = '''||CATEGORY||''' THEN "'||"LEVEL"||'" END) AS "'||LEVEL||'_'||CATEGORY||'"', ',') order by 1,2 desc).extract (
             '//text()'),
          ', ')
          INTO cols_2
    FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT "LEVEL", CATEGORY
            temp
          );
```

I have tried this an declared the cols_2 as `clob` type :-

```
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT (
           RTRIM (
               XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (
                           e,
                              'MAX(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = '''
                           || CATEGORY
                           || ''' THEN "'
                           || "LEVEL"
                           || '" END) AS "'
                           || "LEVEL"
                           || '_'
                           || CATEGORY
                           || '"',
                           ',')
                       ORDER BY 1, DESC).EXTRACT('//text()').getclobval(),','),1)
               ', '),
           1)
  INTO cols_2
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "LEVEL", CATEGORY
          FROM temp);
```

Yet my issue is not resolved ,Im getting an error while trying to execute it as a procedure like :-
[Error in concatenation of `LISTAGG` function[Not a duplicate question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197582/error-in-concatenation-of-listagg-functionnot-a-duplicate-question?noredirect=1#comment113528775_64197582)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `missing keyword` error because you are most likely attempting to run the second query as a standalone query instead of in a PL/SQL block. When you are doing that, you have to remove your `into cols_2` clause. That is your immediate issue that should resolve your error.

Also, based on your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64176155/create-pivot-view-in-sql-from-a-sql-table), using the XML functions will escape your `'` and `"` characters so you will want to make sure to unescape them back to their original characters so you can use them in your dynamic sql query like this:

```
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT (
           RTRIM (
               XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (
                           e,
                              'MAX(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = '''
                           || CATEGORY
                           || ''' THEN "'
                           || "LEVEL"
                           || '" END) AS "'
                           || "LEVEL"
                           || '_'
                           || CATEGORY
                           || '"',
                           ',')
                       ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC).EXTRACT ('//text()'),
               ', '),
           1)
  --INTO cols_2
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "LEVEL", CATEGORY
          FROM temp);
```

Comment: I tried your code with `into v_cols2` inside the procedure window and without it as you have on the SQL comander window, both places i get `[Code: 19011, SQL State: 72000]  ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "PIVOT_VIEW"line 16
ORA-06512: at line 1` error

Comment: Also I have declared the `v_cols2` variable as `long`

Comment: What is `"PIVOT_VIEW"`? There is no reference to anything like that in the select statement.

Comment: That is just my procedure name, it got compiled successfully, but getting the mentioned error, so i just wanted to let you know the error, you can ignore the name part.DB viz or even oracle most of the times shows error at the proc definition even if its an error in a block inside it

Comment: I looked up SO, many posts say that we need add`getclobval(),',') ` for  the error to go away. So I tried the same :  `ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC).EXTRACT ('//text()').getclobval(),','),1) `  the compile was successful but it says `illegal zero length identifier`