# MSSMS - Sql, Select data from table to create a pivot result

Tags: sql-server

I have **TABLE1** with the following columns as `SELECT` result:

```
[ID]  [Name]  [Type]  [Score]
  1  | Aris   |  A   |   100
  1  | Aris   |  B   |   150
  1  | Aris   |  C   |   200
  2  | Nina   |  A   |   1000
  2  | Nina   |  B   |   1500
  2  | Nina   |  C   |   2000
  3  | Mary   |  A   |   10000
  3  | Mary   |  B   |   15000
  3  | Mary   |  C   |   20000
```

What i'm trying to do, is to query **TABLE1** or create a separate view that produce this structure:

```
[Id] [Name]  [Type A] [Type B] [Type C]
  1 | Aris  | 100    | 150    |  200
  2 | Nina  | 1000   | 1500   |  2000
  3 | Mary  | 10000  | 15000  |  20000
```

the result is a pivot table and the problem i'm facing is while grouping all entries...
I already reviewed something similar [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64176155/create-pivot-view-in-sql-from-a-sql-table) but is too complicated for my approach.

Any help will be appreciated! thank you!

Comment: mysql and sql-server are different DBMSes. Tag only one  you are really using.

Comment: what you need is a simple `PIVOT` query. Refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) for syntax and example

Comment: *"is too complicated for my approach."* The solutions you are after are going to be pivoting though; either with the `PIVOT` operator or with conditional aggregation. If pivoting, in the RDBMS, is "too complicated" then do it in the application layer instead. It's up to *you* to understand the answers here if you are going to use them; if you don't understand them you shouldn't be using them.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your highlight, i have already solve it on application layer, my consideration is to learn also a new way using sql syntax. I'm not an expert in sql that's why is "complicated"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, i have managed to approach the above procedure with this query:

```
WITH Pivoted
    AS
    (
    SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT * FROM  TABLE1)
    AS eidos
    
    PIVOT( MAX(Score) FOR [Type] IN ([A],[B],[C])) AS myPivot
    )
    SELECT  
            MAX(ID) AS ID,
            MAX(NAME) AS NAME,
            MAX(A) AS [TYPE A],
            MAX(B) AS [TYPE B], 
            MAX(C) AS [TYPE C]
    FROM Pivoted
```